# Making Chrome open md/markdown file instead of downloading them

Tags: chrome

I'm trying this google chrome [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Markdown%20Preview) that previews `md` files in chrome. But when I open an `md` file from local filesystem, chrome downloads it instead of opening it. So the plugin cannot preview it.

`md` files from the internet are opened as expected. But I want that to work for files on my local filesystem.

My OS is ArchLinux with KDE.

Comment: This is not unix/linux related. Should be on [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: @Patrick: can't you move it there? :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the plugin's webpage you need to "Check 'Allow access to file URLs' in chrome://extensions listing:"  The check box is normally hidden, but there is a tab on the left to open it up.

Comment: In my extensions check box is marked, but still browser download file  and this behavior only for markdown file. For other source code I can see the file in browser.